# VSTO Powerpoint 2010 shared ToggleButton on multiple document Windows

Tags: vb.net, vsto, ms-office, powerpoint

Create a simple VSTO Powerpoint 2010 AddIn with 1 toggle button inside the Ribbon.

Open several presentations, then clik on the toggle button.

The checked state of the toggle button is shared between all document.

How can i resolve this in order to have the same behavior that office's native's toggle-buttons ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off top of head, trap the event that occurs on document open or selection change; invalidate the button and call a routine that determines the state it should have based on the ActivePresentation.

Comment: Yes, beacause it is thread related, and the click event provide you to access the button from curent'w window thread.